# Can't debug android phone on Imac

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android LG g3 phone connected to the Imac.
When i type adb devices - the list is empty.

The debug mode on the phone is enable.
It is working on my macbook-pro without a problem! on both macs i have android studio installed, both EL Capitan.

Maybe someone can help?

Comment: This question is not related to SO. Did you saw a 'Allow debug for the device' dialog on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was that i had to install a driver for my lg g3 phone and restart the mac, after that all good

Answer (score 0):

Check SDK Manager on both machines and see if there are any differences that could cause this.

Comment: Shouldn't need an SDK to use `adb devices`

Answer (score 0):

This will be a guess but are you using the same cable? I have found out some time ago that certain cables will not display debugging information.  Also try resetting connections on AndroidStudio.